# How to ensure Breeze cache is not persisted in local memory

Tags: caching, breeze

I have a project that I am working where data cannot be cached on the client of certain entity types.  Some are Ok, and others are not.

I don't see anything in the documentation or the API that references NOT caching an entity of a particular type, so is there a way to do this to prevent secure information from being cached?

**What have I tried?**

Nothing...  I don't see a way to do this...

**Edit**

As an alternative, if anyone from IdeaBlade could lend a hand in explaining how and where the caching is saving info and where (if anywhere) that information is persisted it may be helpful in alleviating the need to NOT cache.

**Edit 2**

Ok no answer, yet, I changed the title -

How can I ensure no sensitive data is persisted in the local memory after the browser has been shut down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here.

1. How to keep Breeze from holding entities of a type in its in-memory cache.
2. How prevent caching of entities across browser sessions.

Number 2 first: Breeze in memory cache evaporates when the browser session closes and is not shared across browser sessions. You can arrange for local persistence but that's a conscious decision and some small effort. I don't think you have to worry about that.

If you want to prevent a type from being cached in memory at all (really? Why?) you could write a  simple JsonResultsAdapter that zaps the $type parameter for nodes of this entity type and let's the others pass through to the default adapter. Breeze only makes cachable entities out of nodes with a recognized $type. Look that adapter up in the doc.

Comment: I have seen how to write the cache to a string or something but its kind if the opposite of what I always looking for.  Thanks for the reassurance.  As a side note is there any limit to the size of local cache or is that based in the browser?

Comment: Yes it is the opposite. That was my point; you'd have to take an extra step to have the effect that you DONT want. By default you have nothing to worry about IMO. As for your aside, the browser sets the local limit which standards suggest should be  5 meg per origin.